# Flutter speed dials text label going out of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter speed dials text label going out of the screen.

[image]

Comment: did you tried with giving fix width to that container?

Comment: yes, I tried, but in that case, the dial remains open.

Comment: Can you share some some so i can check it?

Comment: I'm not allowed to share my code here. so I'm posting dummy code for testing

Comment: floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
marginEnd: 18,
marginBottom: 20,
icon: Icons.add,
activeIcon: Icons.remove,
visible: true,
closeManually: false,
renderOverlay: false,
overlayColor: Colors.black,
overlayOpacity: 0.5,
tooltip: 'test',
heroTag: 'speed-dial-hero-tag',
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
foregroundColor: Colors.black,
elevation: 8.0,
shape: CircleBorder(),
children: [
SpeedDialChild(
child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
label: ''FIRST CHILD Testing my text for screen size  asasasassa'',
),
],
),

Comment: Checking your code and Approve my edit so other can understand question so you will get solution quickly.

Comment: Give a fontSize to your text